# Magento store direct_url in phtml

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

How to do this using php in .phtml file

```
<a href=" {{store direct_url="contacts"}} ">contact us</a>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try
`<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('contacts');?>">Contact Us</a>`

Comment: That is the same as `{{store url="contacts"}}`  - it adds a slash to the end of the url. `$this->getUrl('', array('_direct' => 'contacts'));` doesn't add a trailing slash and is the same as {{store direct_url="contacts"}}

Answer (score 3):

In order to achieve the same output as **direct_url** within a phtml template, you will want to generate your URL using the **_direct** route parameter.

`<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('', array('_direct' => 'contacts'));?>">Contact Us</a>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this.

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl("contacts")?>">contact Us</a>
```